# Pointer types in c

Tags: c, linux, pointers

I am trying to pass the address of an int[] to a system call. However messages only have fields for char pointers.

I have tried converting the int pointer to a char pointer and back again but the results in the array are not correct.

```
int pidarray[j];
m.m1_p3 = (char*)pidarray;
```

Also I tried to store the address of the array as an integer and pass it through a message integer field.

```
int pidarray[j];
m.m1_i3 = &pidarray;
```

EDIT:

This will be a system call of my creation, aimed at filling an array with pids and copying the data back to the process hence why I need to pass the address of the array. I call the system call a so,

```
_syscall(PM_PROC_NR, GETCHILDPIDS, &m);
```

It fills an array and attempts to copy it back to memory space owned by the calling process. This is done as:

```
sys_vircopy(SELF, (vir_bytes) &test, who_e,(vir_bytes) m_in.m1_i3, sizeof(test));
```

where test is a int[].

How can I send the address of a int[] in this format?

Comment: Please edit your question if you think it is not a duplicate. Why system call are you using? Show the code which is doing the system call.

Answer (score 1):

In C, arrays are decayed into pointers, in particular when passed as arguments.

So just handle that as a pointer. You may need to change the interface of your new system call (e.g. perhaps give it a pointer and a size, or have a convention saying that `pidarray` should be 0 terminated).

BTW, it smells like your system call is useless. You can do all that on Linux in user-land, thru existing [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) using `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...).